# 64 bit Pseudocode decompiler

Tags: tools, decompiler, x86-64

I have a 64 bit program im debugging. 
I found the function i need to learn more about to potentially "fix" the problem (there is no source code available for the program).

To speed  things up, i wanted to decompile and go over it in pseudocode  as my assembler is still quite weak.
However i did not find any working solutions that would work with x64.

I am using only x64 windows platform so linux/mac solutions wont work (hopper is only 32 bit on windows).
Hex-rays is x86 as well.
There was ida-decompiler python scripts that i didn't get to work no matter what i did ( no output or pseudocode was generated).

Is there any other solutions i could try that does support x64 and has pseudocode support?

Comment: Hopper only provides x86 version for windows which is no good for decompiling x64.
Im using pseudo code together with assembler.

Comment: Try x64dbg with snowman. The output isn't always great though, especially on bigger functions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try C4Decompiler and [REC Studio 4](http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/rec.htm).

Comment: Indeed Rec Studio worked.
C4Decompiler however  failed - it started to cause insane mounts of ram, which end up with some serious user account corruption that forced me to clone my account to a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile Hex Rays does have an x64 Decompiler (adding this answer for people reading now, at the time of Jason's answer the decompiler was not yet available), see the [news](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/news.shtml) page:

> 2014/06/04    The x64 decompiler has arrived!

And from the [order](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/order.shtml) page:

> The Decompiler software is available for 5 platforms: x86, x64, ARM32,
>   ARM64, and PowerPC. While x64, ARM64, and PowerPC decompilers can run
>   only on top of IDA Pro, the x86 and ARM32 decompilers can run on top
>   of both IDA Starter or IDA Pro